# How to determine the beginning of Ramadan in non-Muslim countries?

Tags: fiqh, ramadan

How to determine the beginning of Ramadan in non-Muslim countries?

Is it permissible to depend on astronomical accounts or to follow an Islamic country?

Answer (score 9):

“Ramaḍān enters by one of two ways:”

1. By sighting the crescent
2. By completing thirty days of Shabān

Shaykh Ṣālih al-Fawzān, may Allāh protect him, explained:

> The Messenger of Allāh, prayers and peace upon, said: “Begin fasting
>   when you sight the moon, and end fasting when you sight the moon. And
>   if you are unable to sight it, complete the month of Shabān thirty
>   days." **[al-Bukhārī and Muslim]**

Shaykh Ṣāliḥ al-Fawzān, may Allāh protect him, explained:

> “Those who seek to begin fasting the month of Ramaḍān by using
>   astrological calculations have added and innovated into the religion
>   that which    Allāh and Messenger, prayers and peace upon him, did
>   not   command us with.”

**Source:**  [A Concise Study Guide to Fasting](http://embodyislam.files.wordpress.com/2012/04/a-concise-study-guide-to-fasting-2nd-edition3.pdf)

Answer (score 3):

You can prove it by seeing the new moon (the small sliver of it).  Basically that is astronomy, or part of it, I would say you could rely on astronomy if it is trusted, and yes you could also just follow the most closest Islamic country of the same time.

Comment: I know that astronomy calculations utilized in denial is not in evidence.If it is proven impossible to the legitimate vision by astronomy calculations, we reject the vision and beginning of the month !!

Comment: If it was that simple, why Saudi Arabia has a error vacancy rate of around 96 %? First you should observe the moon for the whole month to have a good expectation to where you should look then the time gap to see the crescent moon (and the sighting to be valid) is very small and it is not easy for a not trained person to identify it. you may recognize and seit clearly one day later.